# get_absolute_url: error of Reverse for 'article-detail' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am using class based views to create a post. I have used get_absolute_url to go to the post page after clicking on post but it is giving an error of no reverse match.
this is my modelspy

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings

from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
 class BlogPost(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null=False,blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000 , null=False,blank=False)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
```

this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
         path('',views.home,name="home"),
         path('home2/',HomeView.as_view(),name = "home2"),
         path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(),name = "article-detail"),
         path('add_post/',AddPostView.as_view(),name="add_post"),
      ]
```

this is home2.html:

```
  <ul>
    {%for post in object_list %}
     <li><a href="{%url 'post:article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a>-{{post.author}}<br/>
     {{post.body}}</li>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
```

this is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import ListView,CreateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'post/home.html')

class HomeView(ListView):
         model = BlogPost
         template_name = "post/home2.html"

 class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
          model = BlogPost
         template_name = "post/article_details.html"
         context_object_name = 'post'

 class AddPostView(CreateView):
          model = BlogPost
           template_name = "post/add_post.html"
           fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: `{% url 'post:article-detail' post.pk %}` please change this to `{%url 'post:article-detail' request pk=post.pk %}` is my suggestion

Comment: I think `args` in `get_absolute_url` should be a tuple not a set. Try this.
`return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)),)` or `return reverse('article-detail', args=[str(self.id))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like. I provide 2 methods.

**1st method:**

By using `get_absolute_url`

```
 from django.urls import reverse
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post:article-detail', args=(self.id)) #post is the app_name
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^article/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
```

**home2.html**

```
<ul>
   {%for post in object_list %}
     <li>
        <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">{{post.title}}</a>-{{post.author}}<br/>{{post.body}}
     </li>
   {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

**2nd Method:**

By using `template tag`.Here get `absolute url` with help of `template tag`.

**home2.html**

```
{% load templatehelpers %}
<ul>
{%for post in object_list %}
   <li>
      <a href="{% abs_url 'app_name:article-detail' request pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a>-{{post.author}}<br/>
     {{post.body}}
   </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here we use a new simple tag namely **abs_url** (absolute url) in **templatehelpers.py** (Template tag). And **app_name** is the name of the app.

**templatehelpers.py**

```
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def abs_url(value, request, **kwargs):
    return reverse(value,kwargs=kwargs)
```

Comment: Please add you `views.py` file.

Comment: Is adding an app_name important?

Answer (score 0):

If you change this

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
```

to this

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('home')
```

You will not get the error, but you will not either be redirected to the post you just posted.

So if your goal is to just get rid of this error, but don't care about where you get redirected afterwards, then this is the solution for you.